# Clojure - read text file and enter it as a list

Tags: file, clojure, txt

I am having trouble with some basic IO operations using Clojure. I have a text file which I need to read, split with the "|" character, and enter into a list for later processing. Here are the contents of my text file:

```
1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567 
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867 
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533
```

And here is my current code:

```clj
((defn -main [] 
(println "Enter an option: \n")

(let [choice (read-line)]
  
  (cond (= choice "1") 
        (let [cust-contents (slurp "file.txt")
              nums-as-strings (clojure.string/split cust-contents #"|")
              numbers (map read-string nums-as-strings)]
              (print numbers)
        ) 
  )
) ) )


(-main)
```

I would think this code to work, however here is the error I get when running my program:

```
(; Execution error at user/eval7923$-main (REPL:11).
; EOF while reading
```

Could anyone please guide me on where I went wrong and on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is actually caused when you call `read-string` with argument `" "`.

And where that `" "` comes from? You used the wrong regex in `clojure.string/split`, you should use `#"\|"` instead of `#"|"`.

And even then, you can't call `read-string` on everything, as it would soon crash again, trying to parse `"456-4567"`.

Also, ending parentheses belong to the same line.

If your file contains newlines, you will need [`clojure.string/split-lines`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split-lines) and if you will also implement `2 Display Product Table, 3. Display Sales Table` and so on (I know the context for this code), [`case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case) will be better than `cond`.

Here is your code with some improvements:

```
(ns homework.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as s])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main []
  (println "Enter an option: \n")
  (let [choice (read-line)]
    (case choice
          "1" (->> (s/split-lines (slurp "file.txt"))
                   (mapv #(s/split % #"\|"))
                   println)
          "Wrong number")))

(-main)
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you should not have 2 left parentheses in a row like `((defn ...`.

Also, CSV parsing has many libraries to remove the drudgery of reinventing the wheel.  My favorite is illustrated below:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.csv :as csv]))

(verify
  ; ***** NOTE *****  most CSV has a header line, which is added below for convenience!
  (let [data-str "id|name|address|phone
                  1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
                  2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
                  3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533 "
        entity-maps (csv/csv->entities data-str {:separator \|})]
    (is= entity-maps
      [{:address "123 Here Street", :id "1", :name "John Smith", :phone "456-4567"}
       {:address "43 Rose Court Street", :id "2", :name "Sue Jones", :phone "345-7867"}
       {:address "165 Happy Lane", :id "3", :name "Fan Yuhong", :phone "345-4533"}])))
```

This unit test leaves out the file-reading part as that just complicates things in a unit test.

The above solution is based on [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), which also has a list of documentation sources toward the end.

You can find examine the source code for [tupelo.csv](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/clj/tupelo/csv.clj)
and also [the unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/csv.clj).

---

To clarify your code, here is a cleaned-up version:

```clj
(verify
  (let [data-str        "1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
                         2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
                         3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533 "
        data-lines      (str/split-lines data-str)
        token-table-str (vec (for [line data-lines]
                               (let [token-strs (str/split line #"\|")]
                                 (mapv str/trim token-strs))))]
    (is= token-table-str
      [["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"]
       ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"]
       ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533"]])))
```

Notice that I didn't parse the data past the String stage.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]` to your `lein` dependencies.
Do `lein deps` to install it.

Put into a file e.g. "/home/me/test.csv"

```
1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567 
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867 
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533
```

```
(ns csvread
  (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]))

(defn parse-table [file]
  (csv/parse-csv (slurp file) :delimiter \|))

(defn parse-table-from-string [s]
  (csv/parse-csv s :delimiter \|))
```

Apply it:

```
(parse-table "/home/me/test.csv")
;; => (["1" "John Smith" "123 Here Street" "456-4567"] 
;;     ["2" "Sue Jones" "43 Rose Court Street" "345-7867"] 
;;     ["3" "Fan Yuhong" "165 Happy Lane" "345-4533 "])

(def s "1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567 
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867 
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533")

(parse-table-from-string s)
```