# How to iterate over map of lists and replace the first item of each list? (Clojure)

Tags: loops, recursion, clojure

I have been able to transform a text file into a map containing lists. I have a customer text file, containing the name, address and phone number of customer as follows:

```
{1 (John Smith 123 Here Street 456-4567), 2 (Sue Jones 43 Rose Court Street 345-7867), 3 (Fan Yuhong 165 Happy Lane 345-4533)}
```

I also have a map of products and their value:

```
{1 (shoes 14.96), 2 (milk 1.98), 3 (jam 2.99), 4 (gum 1.25), 5 (eggs 2.98), 6 (jacket 42.99)}
```

And a map of the customer Id (second column), the product Id (third column) and the amount of product bought (4th column), like this

```
{1 (1 1 3), 2 (2 2 3), 3 (2 1 1), 4 (3 3 4)}
```

What I am tasked with is to replace the customer Id value and the product Id value with the name of the customer and the name of the product, which would require me to iterate over the map of lists, take the appropriate element from the customer Map and the product Map, and (cons item) to the appropriate list in the list in the product Map. This is where I am stuck.

I have tried to work around this function, to very little avail.

```
(map #(clojure.edn/read-string (first %)) items)`
```

Also this

```
(defn update-map [m f] 
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] 
    (assoc m k (f v))) {} m))
```

Unless I am completely wrong, I thought that recursion was the only way to iterate over a map but even then, I have no idea how to do in a map containing structures to be traversed and how to replace the items.

Any help would be apreciated

So I actually wrote what I did just above, this if a first posting on stackoverflow

Comment: For context, this is a follow-up of [Clojure - read text file and enter it as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620474/clojure-read-text-file-and-enter-it-as-a-list). Full assignment instructions can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeworkHelp/comments/z72rf3/college_computer_science_tough_assignment_with/). OP, can you use some libraries or do you have to use only core functions? And can you use functions from `clojure.set` (for example, `clojure.set/join`)?

Comment: @MartinPůda Why would this need anything fancier than `into`, `map`/`for`, and `get`?

Comment: Remember Alan Perlis' advice, "Everything should be built top-down, except the first time." Start with (1 1 3): how would you restate it as ("John Smith", "shoes", 3)?

Comment: @Biped Phill here is what I did so far(defn salesMaker
[map1 map2 map3]

(def customerId (nth (get map1 1) 2)
(def custName (nth (get map2 customerId) 1))

(def productId (nth (get map1 1) 2)                     ;the 1 needs to be iterated over for how many lists contained in map
(def prodName (nth (get map3 productId) 1))

(def newSalesList '(custName prodName (nth (get map1) 3)))

Comment: @lcdlv Comments are not suitable to share code. Please edit your
question and add the new insights.  If you have answered your own
question, this is even better. It's fine to create your own answer and
accept it.